# error adding reference in .net 3.5

Tags: .net, dll, reference, sftp

Im trying to add a reference to a dll i downloaded which I want to use for some sftp work.
as soon as i add it i get 
"could not load file or asse3mble....failed to grant minimum permission requests"
Is this to do with my own account permissions?

thanks

DD

Comment: Please provide more information.  What is the exact text of the error? Where is your code running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very detailed but a guess:

If you download an assembly from the internet your machine will not trust it. This is all to do with CAS (Code Access Security). You can find a lot of information about this [here](http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/secWSFive.htm).